# Android AAR unable to resolve field in styleable

Tags: android, android-resources, aar

I have an "android-commons" library of sorts which gets built into an `aar` (it's not a jar). One of the things it contains is a custom implementation of "Typeface" views (most of the classes of TextView, e.g. TypefaceTextView, TypefaceButton etc.). To acomplish this, I've declared the following in my `attrs.xml` (in /res/values):

```
<attr name="fontName" format="string" />
<declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
    <attr name="fontName" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I could then declare a custom style which specified the font name of a `.ttf` file within my assets, which the View would parse and set the custom typeface.

```
// excerpt from TypefaceTextView

public TypefaceTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

private void setCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        Typefaces.setCustomFont(context, attrs, this);
    }
}
```

The `Typefaces` class is a cache for Typefaces and contains utility methods for setting the Typeface to a TextView:

```
// excerpt from Typefaces

public static void setCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, TextView view) {
    String assetPath = getCustomFontPath(context, attrs);
    setCustomFont(context, assetPath, view); // a method that sets the TF to the view
}

public static String getCustomFontPath(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFont);
    String assetPath = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomFont_fontName);
    a.recycle();
    return assetPath;
}
```

Up until now (before Android Studio), for lack of time to modularize this, I had this côde in a few of my projects and it always worked correctly, I could specify `fontName` in a style which I applied to my Views and all was well.

```
<style name="TestStyle">
    <item name="fontName">ApexNew-Bold.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Now, after a switch to AS, gradle and continuous integration, I put all of this into the mentioned "commons" library which gets built into an aar file. When I add a dependency to the aar, I see all of the Typeface classes and can use them as usual (in code or in layouts). The project builds also, but when running it I get the following exception when inflating a layout that has a TypefaceTextView in it:

```
unable to resolve static field 2955 (CustomFont) in Lmy/package/name/widgets/R$styleable
.....
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class my.package.name.widgets.typeface.TypefaceTextView
```

The error is pretty clear, in that it can't find the styleable, but what I can't figure out is why that happens. Here is a `tree` of the unpacked aar:

```
AAR
│   AndroidManifest.xml
│   classes.jar
│   R.txt
│
├───aidl
├───assets
└───res
    └───values
            values.xml
```

`R.txt` contains the following:

```
int attr fontName 0x7f010000
int[] styleable CustomFont { 0x7f010000 }
int styleable CustomFont_fontName 0
```

`/res/values/values.xml` contains the following:

```
"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- From: file:/C:/Users/vjosip/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidCommons/widgets/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml -->
    <eat-comment />

    <attr name="fontName" format="string" />

    <declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
        <attr name="fontName" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Can somebody give an insight as to what could be happening here? I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding it on a few different machines (including the jenkins CI server) - so far the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just now imported from Idea to Android Studio and found the obtainStyledAttributes does not find all attributes (runtime).
Compiling the same code in Idea, the attributes are ok again.
I think you could face the same problem.

Issue has been solved Oct 10, 2014: 
Issue 74140:    Using package name with upper case letters causes class loading issues.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74140

Comment: Hi and sorry for the much-delayed comment... although I've never used upper case letters in package names, it seems that _something_ was fixed in the mean time in Android tools/Studio, because I've built the library (aar) today and now it works just fine. Reverting the dependency to a previous version crashes it again. Since the tools seem to have been the cause of the issue, I'm accepting this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the library is not built with Android Studio - it's done with Jenkins. So the issue seems to have been in the build tools, not AS as previously suggested.